# Swift/XCode build error: Cannot convert value of type [Die] to expected argument type [Die]

Tags: swift, xcode, build-error

Using XCode 8.3.3 which I believe uses Swift 3.1, but not 100% sure (how can you tell?).  Here is the complete code.  Note that when I paste this into a clean Playground, I get no errors.  But within an XCode project, I get the build error on the line "let dice = Dice(withArrayOfDie: arrayOfDie)" in the unit test:

```
let defaultFaceCount = 6
let defaultDieCount = 6

func randomInt(withMaxValue maxValue: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxValue))) + 1
}

class Die
{
    private let m_faceCount: Int     // Constant only set in init
    private var m_faceValue: Int?

    init(numFaces initialFaceCount: Int, withValue initialFaceValue: Int) {
        // Make sure number of faces is greater than 0.
        m_faceCount = (initialFaceCount > 0) ? initialFaceCount : defaultFaceCount

        // Make sure face value is in proper range.
        if initialFaceValue == 0 || initialFaceValue > m_faceCount {
            m_faceValue = randomInt(withMaxValue: m_faceCount)
        }
        else {
            m_faceValue = abs(initialFaceValue)
        }
    }

    convenience init(numFaces initialFaceCount: Int) {
        self.init(numFaces: initialFaceCount,
                  withValue: randomInt(withMaxValue: initialFaceCount))
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(numFaces: defaultFaceCount)
    }

    var faceValue: Int {
        get {
            return m_faceValue!
        }
    }

    var faceCount: Int {
        get {
            return m_faceCount
        }
    }

    func roll() {
        // face values are 1 based!
        m_faceValue = randomInt(withMaxValue: m_faceCount)
    }
}

class Dice {
    var m_dice: [Die]
    var m_occurrencesOf: [Int]

    // Init with a pre-initialized array of Die.  Every Die in
    //   the array must have the same face count.
    init(withArrayOfDie: [Die]) {
        var faceCount = defaultFaceCount
        if withArrayOfDie.isEmpty {
            // If there are no dice, add defaults.
            m_dice = [Die]()
            for _ in 1...defaultDieCount {
                m_dice.append(Die(numFaces: defaultFaceCount))
            }
        }
        else {
            m_dice = withArrayOfDie
            faceCount = m_dice[0].faceCount
        }
        // Keep trace of # of occurrences of each face value.
        m_occurrencesOf = Array(repeating: 0, count: faceCount)
        for die in m_dice {
            m_occurrencesOf[die.faceValue - 1] += 1
        }
    }

    // Init numDice dice, each with numFaces.
    convenience init(numDice count: Int, numFaces faceCount: Int) {
        var dice = [Die]()
        for _ in 1...count {
            dice.append(Die(numFaces: faceCount))
        }
        self.init(withArrayOfDie: dice)
    }

    // Init defaultDieCount dice, each with defaultFaceCount faces.
    convenience init() {
        self.init(numDice: defaultDieCount, numFaces: defaultFaceCount)
    }

    var count: Int {
        return m_dice.count
    }

    // Retrieve the die at the specified (0 based) index.
    func die(atIndex index: Int) -> Die? {
        if !m_dice.isEmpty && index >= 0 && index < m_dice.count {
            return m_dice[index]
        } 
        return nil
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Die? {
        get {
            return die(atIndex: index)
        }
    }
}

// Unit Test
var arrayOfDie = [Die]()
for i in 1...6 {
    arrayOfDie.append(Die())
}
let dice = Dice(withArrayOfDie: arrayOfDie)
// XCTAssertEqual(6, dice.count)
```

I get the build error "Cannot convert value of type [Die] to expected argument type [Die]" on the line "let dice = Dice(withArrayOfDie: arrayOfDie)".  Cannot figure out why the argument which is an array of die does not match the expected init argument type.

Thanks!

Comment: The line `var m_dice: [Die]()` isn't valid. Get rid of the `()`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.   That was a typo in the original post, the code was actually "var m_dice = [Die]()", not "var m_dice: [Die]()".  (Not a type annotation, an initial assignment of a 0 length array).

Comment: It would help if you specified *which* line gives you the build error. EDIT: Particularly since my copy/paste of your code yields **no** build errors.

Comment: The line of code that reports the build error is "let dice = Dice(withArrayOfDie: arrayOfDie)"

Comment: The thing is, if I take the code from this post and put it into a new playground that has nothing else in it, then I was able to get it to work.  But in the larger context of my XCode project that is using unit tests to test the code, I get the error, and there is nothing different.  I just think XCode has bugs in parsing code.  I don't know how to post all the extra code here on Stack Overflow.  Trying to figure that out...

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `()` in `var m_dice: [Die]()`

```
class Dice {
    var m_dice: [Die]
    init(withArrayOfDie dice: [Die]) {
        m_dice = dice
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried both "var m_dice = [Die]()"  and "var m_dice: [Die]" but still get the same error either way.  The former should make it so that m_dice always references a valid array, the latter just uses a type annotation.  I presume for the former I can still modify m_dice in an init().  I presume the latter I must initialize m_dice in an init().  But again, either way I still get the error.  Thanks for your responses!